# Symfony 4 authentication and CORS

Tags: angular, yaml, token, response, symfony4

I have a big problem with my Symfony 4 app which has deployed on heroku.

My first problem which was a cors policy has been in part solved in help of disable the cors on my browser, but I try to have a free browser disabler cors symfony app to show to my parents that don't know how disable the cors.

My second problem it's with the response of my authentication, indeed the server send my user authenticate user entity and the token in the end and I can't keep the token with my front in Angular 11. With a status 200 throw like error. I'm very sad of that, there is few day I try to deploy.

my server response to the login check:
[image: error status 200]

My security.yaml

```
login:
    pattern: ^/api/login_check
    stateless: true
    anonymous: true
    json_login:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

my routes.yaml

```
app_login_check:
  path: /api/login_check
  methods:  ['POST']
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Answer (score -1):

I had the solution of the problem, it's a dump($user), in the LoginListener, that interfer with the response, i had comment that, and the problem has been soluced.[LoginListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mlf6.png)